# Working on Angular Reactive Form Validation, but getting an error while declaring the error message to be displayed

Tags: angular

HTML code :

```html
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Add Product Form</h1>
<div id="form">
  <form [formGroup]="ProductForm" style="background-color: black">
    <p>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Product Name</mat-label>
        <input
          formControlName="productName"
          matInput
          placeholder="Enter Product Name"
        />
        <div
          *ngIf="ProductForm.controls['productName'].invalid && (ProductForm.controls['productName'].dirty || ProductForm.controls['productName'].touched)"
          class="alert"
        >
          <div *ngIf="ProductForm.controls.productName.errors.required">
            This field requires entries
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Product category</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="productCategory" placeholder="Category">
          <mat-option value="Fruits">Fruits</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Vegitables">Vegitables</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Pulses">Pulses</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Liquides">Liquides</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
        <input formControlName="date" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker">
        </mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker> </mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-label for=""> Product Freshness </mat-label>
      <mat-radio-group formControlName="freshness" class="example-radio-group">
        <mat-radio-button
          *ngFor="let fresh of FreshnessList"
          [value]="fresh"
          class="example-radio-button"
        >
          {{ fresh }}
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>

      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Price</mat-label>
        <input
          formControlName="productPrice"
          matInput
          type="number"
          placeholder="Enter Product Price"
        />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearence="outline">
        <mat-label>Comment</mat-label>
        <textarea formControlName="comment" matInput></textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>
  </form>

  <div mat-dialogue-action [align]="'end'">
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" mat-dialog-close="">Close</button>
    <button
      style="margin-left: 8px"
      mat-raised-button
      color="primary"
      mat-dialog-close=""
      (click)="addProduct()"
    >
      {{ACTION}}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

DialogueComponent.ts code:

```typescript
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { ApiService } from "../services/api.service";
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from "@angular/material/dialog";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialogue',
  templateUrl: './dialogue.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialogue.component.scss']
})
export class DialogueComponent implements OnInit {
  FreshnessList = [
    "Fresh",
    "3 days old",
    "5 days old",
    "1 week old",
    "Not for sale",
  ];

  ProductForm!: FormGroup;

  ACTION: string = "Save";

  constructor(
    private formbuilder: FormBuilder,
    private api: ApiService,
    private dialogueRef: MatDialogRef<DialogueComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public editData: any
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ProductForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      id: "",
      productName: ["", Validators.required],
      productCategory: ["", Validators.required],
      date: ["", Validators.required],
      freshness: ["", Validators.required],
      productPrice: ["", Validators.required],
      comment: ["", Validators.required],
    });

    if (this.editData) {
      this.ACTION = "UPDATE";
      this.ProductForm.controls["id"].setValue(this.editData.id);
      this.ProductForm.controls["productName"].setValue(
        this.editData.productName
      );
      this.ProductForm.controls["productCategory"].setValue(
        this.editData.productCategory
      );
      this.ProductForm.controls["date"].setValue(this.editData.date);
      this.ProductForm.controls["freshness"].setValue(this.editData.freshness);
      this.ProductForm.controls["productPrice"].setValue(
        this.editData.productPrice
      );
      this.ProductForm.controls["comment"].setValue(this.editData.comment);
    }
    console.log(this.editData);
  }

  addProduct() {
    console.log("add product");
    if (!this.editData) {
      console.log(" is editable");
      console.log(this.ProductForm?.value);

      if (this.ProductForm.valid) {
        const tempData: any = this.ProductForm.value;
        const formData: any = { ...tempData, ["id"]: tempData.productName };
        this.api.postProduct(formData).subscribe({
          next: (res) => {
            alert("product added successfully");
            this.ProductForm.reset();
            this.dialogueRef.close("save");
          },
          error: () => {
            alert("error while adding the product");
          },
        });
      }
    } else {
      this.updateProduct();
    }
  }

  updateProduct() {
    this.api.putProduct(this.ProductForm.value, this.editData.id).subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        alert("Product Updated successfully");
        this.ProductForm.reset();
        this.dialogueRef.close("update");
      },
      error: () => {
        alert("Error while updating ");
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide an error message? When and where does it happen?

Comment: Your code would be a lot cleaner if you used `patchValue()` on the form group instead of using `setValue()` on each form control.